# Get the previous number parent id and update the other column

Tags: sql

I have a query in SQL:

I have a table like this

```
id  typeid amount   created date          parenttypeid
38  2   5000.00    2016-12-08 15:01:27.433  NULL
39  2   5000.00    2016-12-08 15:01:27.433  NULL
40  1   5000.00    2016-12-08 15:01:27.433  NULL
41  4   5000.00    2016-12-08 15:01:27.437  NULL
42  1   5000.00    2016-12-08 15:01:27.437  NULL
43  4   5000.00    2016-12-08 15:01:27.437  NULL
44  1   5000.00    2016-12-08 15:01:27.437  NULL
45  1   5000.00    2016-12-08 15:01:27.437  NULL
46  3   5000.00    2016-12-08 15:01:27.437  NULL
47  3   5000.00    2016-12-08 15:01:27.437  NULL
```

I need to find the immediate number of the specific number and get its parent id and update in parenttypeid field

for instance:

type id : 4, its previous value is 3, we have 2 rows with type id 3. I need to get the latest type id's parent id - ie., 47. and update 47 to parenttypeid column.

I need only sql query

Can any one help.

Regards,
Sriram

Comment: Tag which RDBMS you are using.

Comment: The task sounds to me as if it could be an assignment. If so, please note that this is not a we-will-do-your-homework community. Furthermore, could you please specify, which steps you have taken to solve your problem on yourself? Are you stuck at any specific point of the problem? People here will happily help you, if you show that you provide some effort by yourself.

Comment: I am new to sql. Whats wrong in asking questions.

Comment: If you dont know, just dont comment Paul.

Comment: Hi Jibin, sql server 2014

Comment: LAG will it work in sql server 2014?

Comment: iam getting an exception like - Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you what you need assuming you use SQL Server and update part I leave you as a try

```
select top 1 id from table where typeid=4-1 order by id desc
```

Comment: I am using sql server 2014

Comment: can you please explain the above query. iam not getting it.

Comment: @JibinBalachandran well spotted. I corrected with TOP :)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this (SQL SERVER 2012 or higher):**

```
;WITH ToUpdate 
AS (
     SELECT TOP 1 id,LAG(id,1) OVER (ORDER BY typeid DESC) AS [val]
     FROM [YourTable] 
     WHERE typeid=(LAG(typeid) OVER (ORDER BY typeid DESC))-1 
     ORDER BY id DESC
) 

Update Y
SET Y.id=C.[val]
FROM CTE C
INNER JOIN [YourTable]  Y ON Y.id=C.id
```

Comment: Bala,  Still iam facing issue while executing your query

Comment: Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses.